# How do I use multiple writers with tdb?

Tags: c, database, samba, tdb, dbm

I'm using tdb to try to get acquainted with database management in C on Linux. Per [tdb's description](https://tdb.samba.org/group__tdb.html)

> tdb is a Trivial database.
>
> In concept, it is very much like GDBM, and BSD's DB **except that it
> allows multiple simultaneous writers and uses locking internally to
> keep writers from trampling on each other**. tdb is also extremely
> small. Interface
>
> The interface is very similar to gdbm except for the following:
>
> - different open interface. The tdb_open call is more similar to a traditional open()
> - no tdbm_reorganise() function
> - no tdbm_sync() function. No operations are cached in the library anyway
> - added transactions support
>
> A general rule for using tdb is that the caller frees any returned
> TDB_DATA structures. Just call free(p.dptr) to free a TDB_DATA return
> value called p. This is the same as gdbm.

Now I wanted to make a small test program to test multiple write-connections to my database. But it fails.

```
#include <tdb.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   struct tdb_context * tdb = tdb_open("test.tdb", 0, 0,
           O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP);
   if(!tdb){
       printf("%s\n", tdb_errorstr(tdb));
   } else {
       printf("Database successfully opened!\n");
   }
   
   struct tdb_context * anothertdb = tdb_open("test.tdb", 0, 0,
           O_RDWR| O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP);  //why does this fail?
   if(!anothertdb){
       printf("%s\n", tdb_errorstr(anothertdb));
   } else {
       printf("Another reader successfully opened!\n");
   }
   
   if(tdb_close(anothertdb)){
       printf("Error while closing database!\n");
   } else {
       printf("closing anothertdb-connection\n");
   }
   
   if(tdb_close(tdb)){
       printf("Error while closing database!\n");
   } else {
       printf("closing tdb-connection\n");
   }
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Database successfully opened!

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 240ms; user: 0ms; system: 20ms
```

If I open just a **single** connection to the database there are no problems. How do I open multiple readers on a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is the call to `tdb_errorstring` after `tdb_open` fails:

```
if(!anothertdb){
       printf("%s\n", tdb_errorstr(anothertdb));
}
```

It's perhaps not obvious that this can't work, but there's good reason to suspect that it can't work, because `anothertdb` is most certainly `NULL` when `tdb_errorstr` is called, and it's reasonable to assume that `tdb_errorstr`'s argument must be a valid pointer to a `struct tdb_context`. In fact, that's true; practically the first thing that `tdb_errorstring` does is to try to dereference its argument in order to extract the last error code.

In short, there's no way to extract a custom error string from the result of a `tdb_open` failure; all you can do is what you would do for a `NULL` return from, for example, `fopen()`: call `perror()` in the hopes that `errno` will be set to something meaningful. If you do that, you will see an error message instead of a crash:

```
$ ./tdb_test 
Database successfully opened!
open 2: Device or resource busy
```

The library seems to have a way to send `tdb_open` errors to a configured logging system, but the default configured logging system just throws the error calls away without doing anything. I didn't read the docs to see if there is a description of how to configure a logger; you might want to look into that.

I'm not defending this API design, by the way. Just reporting it.

OK, so now on to your actual question: how do you open multiple connections to a TDB database? And the answer is, you have to do that from multiple processes. An individual process can open as many TDBs as it wants to, but it can only open each of them once (at a time). According to a comment in the source code, that's a result of the way that `fcntl()` locks work, which seems like a reasonable explanation to me.

So if you want to try a multiple-reader, multiple-writer scenario, you're going to have to either run multiple processes, or fork multiple children from a parent process. Threading won't work, because two threads in the same process can't open the same TDB either. It's one open *per process*.

Also, if you choose to fork multiple children, remember that you will need to call `tdb_open` only after you fork, because if you open a TDB in the parent process, it will still be open in the child.

As a final note, please get in the habit of writing warning and error messages to `stderr`, which is normally not buffered so that you have a much better chance that the error message will become visible when you output it, as opposed to some later moment when the stdio library chooses to flush the stdout output buffer. That's not actually a problem here, but it could have been and you're much better off using `stderr` for that purpose (which is its intended purpose, hence the name).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Yes there is a setter for a custom logging function, so you'd have to write it yourself. This is not the cleanest code but it is good to know I have to fork multiple processes. The multiple writers was a reason I wanted tdb over gdbm. I will still use tdb as I might have some process management for my project in the future, but for now it shall be one process.

Comment: @KeyaKersting: There is a way to supply a custom logging function, but the details aren't well documented. (Fortunately, the code is straight-forward.) The API, on the other hand, is, umm, "not well thought out". But I did manage to do it, and it produced a more meaningful logging message: `(Error) proc 2: tdb_open_ex: test.tdb (2053,12716901) is already open in this process`. So I guess it's worth doing. Maybe I'll clean it up and post it somewhere.